# Tagging the index package as opposed to indexing in general

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Should there be a tag for the [`index`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/index) package? Being a rather generic term, it's hard to search for.

There's a tag [indexing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indexing) which covers generic index-related issues. This isn't necessarily appropriate for issues that are specific to one particular package.

There's a tag [index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/index) with only two questions: [How to display index entries on the same line as the text being indexed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292100/how-to-display-index-entries-on-the-same-line-as-the-text-being-indexed) which is about LaTeX's built-in indexing facilities, and the question I just posted [babel and index both redefine \markboth and \markright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292410/babel-and-index-both-redefine-markboth-and-markright) which is about the `index` package.

If a tag is warranted, what should it be called? [index-package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/index-package)?

A tag called [index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/index) is likely to be used to mean indexing in general.
In fact, should [index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/index) be made a synonym of [indexing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indexing) to avoid being recreated?

Comment: `[index-package]` seems the best idea still available.  very slippery situation, but not unique.

Comment: @barbarabeeton seems to have been a widespread practice in the early days for many package authors to simply "capture" a topic, naming the package as the topic, the macros according to the topic, with no prefix whatsoever....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that [index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/index) should be made a synonym of [indexing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indexing), and [index-package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/index-package) should be created for the package, as barbara suggests. This is similar to the situation with [citing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citing) and [cite-package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cite-package).